# Ethernet won't work unless I set the speed to 100

Tags: 14.04, ethernet

I'm currently on 14.04 LTS, but I been testing on 12.04 LTS as well and the same problem occurs. My motherboard is a MSI Z97 MPOWER MAX AC.

Basically, the ethernet is detected but it doesn't connect to anything: the Internet, the local computers, I cannot even access the router.

Here's my ifconfig output:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 44:8a:5b:98:48:22  
          inet addr:192.168.0.105  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::468a:5bff:fe98:4822/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:40531 errors:7461 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:7461
          TX packets:40355 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:46484780 (46.4 MB)  TX bytes:4380158 (4.3 MB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7400000-f7420000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5068 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5068 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:513144 (513.1 KB)  TX bytes:513144 (513.1 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e8:2a:ea:06:38:f8  
          inet addr:192.168.0.102  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ea2a:eaff:fe06:38f8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:305 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:130 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:59252 (59.2 KB)  TX bytes:17414 (17.4 KB)
```

ethtool eth0 output:

```
Supported ports: [ TP ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Full 
Supported pause frame use: No
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Full 
Advertised pause frame use: No
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Speed: 1000Mb/s
Duplex: Full
Port: Twisted Pair
PHYAD: 2
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: on
MDI-X: on (auto)
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
               drv probe link
Link detected: yes
```

My WIFI does work.

Furthermore, if I manually set the speed to 100:

```
sudo ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex full autoneg off
```

Then eth0 does connect to the Internet. But of course that is unbearably slow.

**Update:** Ethernet seems to be working on-and-off randomly on separate bootup of Ubuntu. My current guess is that there's some driver conflict for the Intel I218-V Gigabit LAN controller that's running into some race condition on boot. Will update if I find a solution.

**Final Update** Fixed by reinstalling the driver and deleting eth0 from /etc/network/interfaces and then running `dhclient eth0`.

Comment: After the computer was off for an entire night I came back to find the ethernet working to full capacity. Flaky is weird but at least the problem is gone.

I'll reopen the question and investigate further if the issue resurfaces.

Question will be closed in another day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here are the things I did.  My "Wired Connection 1" (eth0) was recreated as "Auto Ethernet":

1. Manually reinstall driver. In my case, I built Intel's e1000e and modprobe rmmod + add it.
2. Edit network connections and delete the ethernet connection, the UI did not reflect that it was removed, so I'm not sure if this step or the next triggered the remove.
3. Delete the eth0 entry from /etc/network/interfaces. If it didn't exist, create the entry manually, `ifconfig eth0 up` and then delete it.
4. reboot the machine, run `dhclient eth0`.
5. reboot again.

Answer (score 0):

Does your router support 1000 Mbps (gigabit) ethernet? If not, I'd assume it should auto-negotiate a slower speed, but maybe it's not.

And I've read that bad / low quality / damaged cables or plugs won't work correctly at all speeds, maybe that's the case & it's causing errors are higher speeds, and the "errors:7461" line above.

And just wondering, how unbearably slow is your internet, if 100 Mbps is too slow? What speeds are you actually getting? WiFi is generally "fast enough" for almost everyone everywhere using the internet, and it's only 11 / 54 / 100 Mbps. [[1]](http://forums.cnet.com/7723-7585_102-298948/internet-connection-speed-vs-network-speed/) Maybe streaming high-def movies, or file transfers on your local network would suffer though

Comment: The router is a TP-Link AC 1750. Gigabit ethernet works on Windows just fine.

at 100Mpb, I'm getting around ~100kb download speed for some reason. In my case I believe something more complicated was going on. My WIFI is very fast ~2 MB/sec, but I was also interested in getting my ethernet working and finding out what's wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Intermittent problems are tricky. Could be almost anything,  driver/kernel, hardware, wire that only works if it's bent "just right", maybe even power or grounding, static, other interference, microwaves (but most of those would probably affect the wifi too)... trying an older/newer kernel (older/newer live Ubuntu) could see if it gets better/worse?

Comment: I tried booting with a 12.04 LTS livecd and a gentoo live DVD. The problem was still there. Seems to be finally fixed when I reinstalled the driver, removed and recreated the eth0.